# "Вывалили в дилижансе"

Tags: фраза, значение

У Льва Толстого в произведении "Юность" есть фраза:

> Я знал, что Сонечка с матерью была за границею, где они пробыли года два и где, рассказывали, их *вывалили в дилижансе* и Сонечке изрезали лицо стеклами кареты, отчего она будто бы очень подурнела

Что значит "вывалили в дилижансе"? В смысле выбросили на ходу?

Comment: *"изрезали лицо стеклами кареты"* - судя по всему, дилижанс (карета) перевернулся при неудачном повороте, и они из него *вывалились*. (Таг "дореформенная-орфография" здесь как-то мало подходит).

Comment: Я знаю что тег не подходит. Но без тегов не пускало, а другой я не придумал. Если знаете вариант получше, предложите пожалуйста

Answer (score 5):

Сейчас есть возвратный глагол "вывалиться".  Должен быть и глагол "вывалить".  Он и есть, но сейчас не применяется к людям.  Можно вывалить содержимое сумки, но не человека.  В 19 веке, судя по этому и другим текстам, применительно к человеку "вывалился" означало, что он выпал сам, а "вывалили" - что он выпал по чужой вине (не обязательно по злому умыслу).  Примеры из корпуса русского языка:

> Вечеру был я на бале у герцога, дам нескольких опрокинули в коляске, ушибли и вывалили в грязь. [Д. М. Волконский. Дневник. 1812-1814 гг (1812-1813)]

Вряд ли кто-то на балу специально поиздевался над дамами таким образом.  Очевидно, случилась авария.

> Вывезли они меня с извозчиком туда за Ваганьково кладбище, в степь, сняли салоп, да и вывалили в снег: «Ступай, говорит, дамой!» [М. А. Воронов. Арбузовская крепость (1864)] [омонимия не снята] ←…→

А здесь - вывалили специально.

> Буду писать Вам на этих же днях. Вывалили меня в канаву, на всем скаку (лошадь испугалась, и как я не сломал ногу, ― истинно единому богу известно). [Г. И. Успенский. Письма (1887)] [омонимия не снята]

А здесь не было злого умысла. Лошадь просто испугалась и понесла.

> Гедеонов дал приказание своим чиновникам сопровождать кареты воспитанниц до школы, чтобы они не могли из окон говорить с своими обожателями, ехавшими рядом. Чиновников обожатели оттискивали от окон кареты, а одного чиновника, более ревностного, вывалили из дрожек в грязь.

А здесь вывалили намерено.

> При Гамалее в 1836 году был единственный на моей памяти приезд государя в Тамбов. К этому заранее делались большие приготовления; весь город был в суете. Дворянство должно было дать бал. Дамы заказывали и выписывали себе разные наряды; мужчинам портной Никандр Великолепов шил короткие белые штаны, все запасались шелковыми чулками и башмаками с пряжками, ибо такова была в то время необходимая форма в присутствии царственных особ. Помню, как нас, детей, повезли смотреть на въезд. Мы ждали, ждали, но напрасно. К вечеру прискакал курьер с известием, что государя близ Чембар вывалили из коляски и он сломал себе ключицу.

Кто бы посмел намеренно выкидывать государя из коляски? Очевидно, здесь это было без злого умысла.

Comment: "вывалили ИЗ дрожек",  "вывалили ИЗ коляски", "вывезли... и вывалили В снег".     В Ваших примерах самое близкое к толстовскому "вывалили в дилижансе" — это "опрокинули В коляске... и вывалили в грязь". ///"Вывалили в средстве передвижения (читай — вывалили внутри средства передвижения) — это, все-таки, уникальное "ноу хау" Льва Николаевича

Comment: "..Он и есть, но сейчас не применяется к людям. Можно вывалить содержимое сумки, но не человека. В 19 веке, " - точно так же это, по моему, работает и сейчас. :) Если вы хотите подчеркнуть именно грубость и жесткость такого обращения с кем-то, - как с неодушевленным предметом.  
"вывалили из дилижанса" - а в примере выше акцент, возможно, не на конкретный дилижанс - а на дилижанс, ткскзт, как общий вид перевозок и транспорта, поэтому "в".

Comment: @Пилум - сейчас в Корпусе таких примеров словоупотребления больше нет.  И нет, раньше "вывалили" писали не для подчёркивания грубости и жестокости.

Comment: не знаю, что там есть в этом корпусе или нет, а в реальности оно встречается :)  
"...потому что не дорос еще в кабине-то ездить, вывалили как дрова и сказали.."
https://newsland.com/user/4296752974/content/umer-glava-severnoi-korei-kim-chen-ir/4272084

Comment: и вообще ничего необычного в подобном метафорическом (или не очень) использовании глаголов нет."выбросили", "выкинули"... и всякое прочее схожее для иных случаев.

Comment: В гугле можно найти много чего. Это метафорическое использование.

Comment: @Пилум собсвенно дилижанс и есть вид услуг, объединяющий концепции почтового транспорта и чартера, а не конретное транспортное средство, которое зовется "карета дилижанса". Само слово по своему значению в языке-оригинали это подчеркивает. Просто современное использование слова "дилижанс" искажено некорректными переводами популярных произведений и фильмов.